# Chain of responsibility vs Reflection

Tags: c#, design-patterns, reflection

Sometime ago I removed a chain of responsibility in a web site that I'am working on. 
The chain would call a method to generate a dynamic form for the website. Every object called would either return their form or "pass the ball" to the next object to retrieve the form.
The website has around 300+ classes with this logic, no big deal in terms of performance but I found it horrible to see it and debugging it.

So I decided to remove the chain call and just replaced it with reflection, I know what object I have to call by a unique static "name" (the same name was used in the chain to check if the object has to load the form or "pass the ball") of the class and by foreaching all the objects in a list I'll check that name to be sure to call the correct class/method.

I know that reflection is supposed to be slower in terms of performance but after some tests I can't see any sustantial difference and since the code is much cleaner it's easier to understand and debug.

So my **question** is:

*Is this a correct approach or is there any better pattern to use in a case like this ?*

I feel like I use reflection more then I should when I'am coding and I don't know if it is always the better option.

*This in 1 class:*

```
foreach (TemplateHandler t in objectList)
{
    if (t.GetType().GetProperty("serviceCode") != null)
    {
        if (t.GetType().GetProperty("serviceCode").GetValue(t).ToString() == serviceCodeToCallFromParam)
        {       
            return t.GetTemplateParam(serviceCodeToCallFromParam/*, ...other params...*/);
        }
    }
}
```

*over this in 300+ class:*

```
public override List<Form> GetTemplateParam(string serviceCode)
{
    if (serviceCode == ClassServiceCode)
    {
        // long form logic build.
        //..
    }
    else
    {
        if (successor != null)
            form = successor.GetTemplateParam(serviceCode);
    }
    return form;
}
```

Comment: Given that you have working code, I think that this question would be a better fit for the Code Review site https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Maybe you are right, should I insert the question directly there or is there a way to "move" it ?

Comment: There is a lot you don't have to worry about on a web server.  Response time is dominated by network latency first, the user's browser rendering time next.  So dozens of milliseconds at a minimum, gives you lots of breathing room that reflection can't put a dent into.  Not until you have to service hundreds of page requests every second, you tend to know ahead of time when it gets close to that.

Answer (score 1):

Reflection solution looks better if I have to choose from those two. Passing ball for 300 times looks meaningless.

But, as you noted, the performance might be the issue. If you already know the class to call for getting work done, why not implement something like Builder or Factory pattern to create an instance of appropriate class and get the work done through.

Even simpler is the `switch-case` structure. Put and creation code in `switch-case` and use the resultant object to do work.

**Edit 1:**

```
public T CreateTemplate<T>() where T : ITemplate
{
    ITemplate template = null;
    if(typeof(T) == typeof(Type1Template))
        template = new Type1Template(....);
    else if(typeof(T) == typeof(Type2Template))
        template = new Type2Template(....);
    else
        throw new TemplateException("Template type is not configured.");

    return (T)template;
}
```

**Edit 2**

See if something like below helps then:

```
public T CreateTemplate<T>()
{
    ITemplate template = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    return template;
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the suggestion. I used the factory pattern before but with a reflection implementation to retrieve all classes that were needed to instantiate dynamically.([link](https://danielggarcia.wordpress.com/2014/02/15/patrones-de-creacion-i-factory-patterns/)) so at this point it would be the same to keep my original code. 

You suggest the switch-case but what should I do: 300+ switch-case for every object call ? That seems a little odd or maybe I'am not getting your idea about this one.